# JQuery Slider pause

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a website that has a slider  need to make it pause when hovering over the slide but I have zero knowledge of jquery, can someone help?

This is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slides').slidesjs({ 
        height: 235,
        navigation: false,
        pagination: false,
        effect: {
           fade: {
               speed: 400
            }
        },
        callback: {
            start: function(number)
            {           
                $("#slider_content1,#slider_content2,#slider_content3").fadeOut(500);
            },
            complete: function(number)
            {           
                $("#slider_content" + number).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
            }       
        },
        play: {
            active: false,
            auto: true,
            interval: 6000,
            pauseOnHover: true
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using old version of the library. I used version `3.0.4` and it worked fine.
See the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkF5t/